# Switching a picture in my android application takes too long

Tags: java, android

I am making a game in which you can click on a card to change it randomly to another card. The image file for one card is 370x512 png and it size is more or less 200 kb. My problem is the process in which the imageView changes its picture from one card to another is very slow and lasts almost two seconds. The other problem is that if you click too fast on the card the class crashes. I've tried it already with an ImageButton, with a button and an ImageView and I tried it with 11 ImageViews (there are 11 different cards in the game) who are always there but only one of it is visible. I don't have any clue why the card changing process takes so much time. Here is my code to change the card. This code is with a button and an ImageView:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static String dampfhammerData = "dampfhammerData";
SharedPreferences DampfhammerData;

public int nextCard;
public int lastCard = 0;

public int all=3;
public int buddy=3;
public int dampfhammer=3;
public int frauen=3;
public int links=3;
public int rechts=3;
public int maenner=3;
public int questionmaster=3;
public int regel=3;
public int themenrunde=3;
public int zaehlen=3;
public int deck = 44;

public String version;

ImageView Karte;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void changeCard(View view) {
    selectCard();
}

public void selectCard(){
    lastCard = nextCard;
    if(deck > 0) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        nextCard = (rand.nextInt(10));
        if(nextCard != lastCard) {
            checkCardDeck();
        }else {
            selectCard();
        }
    }else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, End.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public void checkCardDeck(){
    Karte = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.karte);

    switch (nextCard) {
        case 0:
             if(all > 0){
                 all--;
                 deck--;
                 Karte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.all);
             }else {
                 selectCard();
             }
            break;
        case 1:
            if(zaehlen > 0){
                zaehlen--;
                deck--;
                Karte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.zaehlen);
            }else {
                selectCard();
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if(buddy > 0){
                buddy--;
                deck--;
                Karte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buddie);
            }else {
                selectCard();
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if(themenrunde > 0){
                themenrunde--;
                deck--;
                Karte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.themenrunde);
            }else {
                selectCard();
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            if(dampfhammer > 0){
                dampfhammer--;
                deck--;
                Karte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dampfhammer);
            }else {
                selectCard();
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            if(links > 0){
                links--;
                deck--;
                Karte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.links);
            }else {
                selectCard();
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            if(rechts > 0){
                rechts--;
                deck--;
                Karte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rechts);
            }else {
                selectCard();
            }
            break;
        case 7:
            if(frauen > 0){
                frauen--;
                deck--;
                Karte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.frauen);
            }else {
                selectCard();
            }
            break;
        case 8:
            if(maenner > 0){
                maenner--;
                deck--;
                Karte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.maenner);
            }else {
                selectCard();
            }
            break;
        case 9:
            if(questionmaster > 0){
                questionmaster--;
                deck--;
                Karte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.questionmaster);
            }else {
                selectCard();
            }
            break;
        case 10:
            if(regel > 0){
                regel--;
                deck--;
                Karte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.regel);
            }else {
                selectCard();
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Wollen sie das Spiel verlassen?") //
            .setMessage("Das aktuelle Spiel wird abgebrochen und sie kehren zum Startbildschirm zurück, wollen sie das wirklich?") //
            .setPositiveButton(("Ja"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(("Nein"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    builder.show();
}
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think maybe because of recursion issues, i.e. you're calling `selectCard()` from within `selectCard()` .. you have to structure this another way.

Answer (score 0):

If your deck of cards consists of 11 cards that each appear four times (I think that's right based on looking at the code), you can create a random shuffle like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> deckList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i=0; i<11; i++) {
  deckList.add(i); deckList.add(i); deckList.add(i); deckList.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(deckList);
```

By instead picking a random next card and retrying when it's a repeat, you're using a very inefficient and unpredictable process, especially since the retries are recursive, increasing the size of the call stack.

You will of course have to make other changes to use my deck in your code, but it should be quite a bit faster.